# Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines

I want to create a VSTS build with npm package auditing capabilities using npm audit. I added a few tasks to run npm audit. The command runs and I can see the details in the console/logs for all the packages. However, the task fails complaining about not finding a logs file. Any idea on how I can get the builds to stop working if I find a high vulnerability package?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
This is the final line in the result when I run npm audit locally[image]
Notice how it displays vulnerabilities in categories. I want the build to not proceed if there is a non-zero value for High vulnerability.

Comment: The "couldn't find a debug log ..." is the warning instead of error? What's the result if you call that command on local machine? On the other hand, I am not clear about “Any idea on how I can get the builds to stop working if I find a high vulnerability package", can you provide the details.

Comment: On local machine, it returns the list of npm packages in the solution together with details on the vulnerability status.

As part of the build process, I want the build to fail once there are any packages encountered with a higher vulnerability status.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same error, but then realize that I am using incorrect custom command for npm task:

it was "`npm install gulp -g`", but should be "`install gulp -g`" (without npm).

For me it helps.

Comment: Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the way to stop/fail build directly if there is a non-zero value for High vulnerability.

The workaround is that you can do it through PowerShell with [Build log REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to analysis whether there is related information in the log, then fail the build (Write-error …) (Run the powershell through PowerShell task)